# Get data from .pickle

Tags: python, model, pickle, text-classification, tf-idf

I have a model of Multinomial NB():

```
text_clf_NB = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                      ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                      ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
                      ])
   
text_clf_NB.fit(Train_X_NB, Train_Y_NB)
```

I save it to .pickle

```
pickle.dump(text_clf_NB, open("NB_classification.pickle", "wb"))
```

In another case I load this model:

```
clf = pickle.load(open("NB_classification.pickle", "rb"))
```

Can you help me, please, how can I get sparse matrix of Train data? I mean I want to get values of Train_X_NB after TfidfTransformer from clf?